# Нумерация для переключения между страницами

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать на чистом JS, переключение номера страницы, при клике на кнопки и на цифры?

```
<div class="btns-pages">
    <button  class="btn-left" type="submit"></button>
    <div class="nam-page nam-active">1</div>
    <div class="nam-page">2</div>
    <div class="nam-page">3</div>
    <div class="nam-page">4</div>
    <div class="nam-page">5</div>
    <button  class="btn-right" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: Вам наверно надо не только листать параметры, но и загружать данные определённых страниц же?

Comment: Конечно полный функционал было бы здорово увидеть и разобраться, что к чему. Но так как данное решение ищу в учебных целях буду рад любой полезной информации. К сожалению, в сети ничего не нашел.

Comment: Могу написать пару вариантов - через `ajax`, `fletch`, `axios` и на `jquery`. Смотря что хотите видеть.

Comment: Так же надо понимать откуда будете брать данные и в каком виде, и как их хотите выводить.

Comment: Пока уровень начальный)) подойдет что-нибудь по-проще.  Данный переключатель страниц, предполагал так и использовать элементарно, для перехода между html-страницами. Понимаю, что можно без перезагрузки страницы. Будет здорово если с помощью ajax покажете реализацию.

Comment: Смотрю уже дали ответ... Ну а запросы можете найти тогда в интернете самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPD // добавил комментарии по просьбе ТС

P.S. стили не делал, но могу по желанию

```js
document.querySelector('.btns-pages').addEventListener('click', e => { // вешаем один обработчик события клика на весь блок
  const { target } = e;  // цель, на которую мы кликнули
  const targetClassList = target.classList;  // массив классов цели, на которую мы кликнули
  const allNumPages = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('.num-page')];  // массив всех нумерованых блоков (блоки с классом .num-page), оператор '...' здесь не просто так
  const activePageNumber = allNumPages.findIndex(i => i.classList.contains('num-active'));  // номер (индекс) ранее выбранной страницы
  
  switch(true) {  // этот оператор смотрит на какую кнопку мы кликнули
    case targetClassList.contains('btn-left'): return activePageNumber && setNum(-1, true);  // если кликнули на кнопку влево
    case targetClassList.contains('btn-right'): return  (activePageNumber - allNumPages.length + 1) && setNum(1, true);  // если кликнули на кнопку вправо
    case targetClassList.contains('num-page'): return setNum(target.innerHTML);  // если кликнули прямо на число
  }
  
  function setNum(num, direction = null) {  // функция, которая задает выбранную страницу. параметр num - какую цифру мы выбрали (если мы нажали на цифру). параметр direction - направление стрелки, которую мы выбрали (если мы нажали на стрелку)
    allNumPages[activePageNumber].classList.remove('num-active'); // убирает класс .num-active с ранее выбранной страницы
    // здесь самый сок
    // если в вызываемой функции указан аргумент direction (он true или false), то берем индекс ранее выбранной цифры и плюсуем/минусуем 1, чтобы активировать предыдущую/следующую цифру
    // плюсовать или минусовать указывает аргумент num, который равен -1 либо 1
    // если в вызываемой функции не указан аргумен direction (он равен null) - значит мы кликнули прямо на число. берем содержимое выбранной цифры (через innerHTML) и по полученому индексу делаем элемент активным
    (allNumPages[direction === null ? target.innerHTML - 1 : activePageNumber + num]).classList.add('num-active') ;
  }
});
```

```css
.btns-pages {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btns-pages > * {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num-page {
  padding: 10px;
}

.num-page.num-active {
  border: 1px solid #e3c596;
  color: #e3c596;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns-pages">
    <button  class="btn-left" type="submit"><-</button>
    <div class="num-page num-active">1</div>
    <div class="num-page">2</div>
    <div class="num-page">3</div>
    <div class="num-page">4</div>
    <div class="num-page">5</div>
    <button  class="btn-right" type="submit">-></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Решение то, что надо! Спасибо! Стили не нужны, а вот описание js кода было бы не лишним, для новичков))

Comment: @ИванЦверкунов, добавил комментарии по Вашей просьбе. если будут трудности с пониманием кода, я могу сам код расписать по-проще для более удобного понимания

Comment: Спасибо! С комментариями намного лучше.

Comment: Будет время распишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. А то уж совсем мой мозг отказывается принимать.
{ target } что за скобки...
почему с оператором "..." показывает содержимое массива, а без нет...
короче тяжко, но грызу))

Comment: @ИванЦверкунов, конечно. `{target}` - это прием, который называется **деструктуризация**, подробно [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta). это всего лишь простой способ присваивать переменные

Comment: @ИванЦверкунов, `document.querySelectorAll('.num-page')` нам возвращает **коллекцию** найденных элементов. но эта **коллекция** не является настоящим массивом, потому на ней нельзя применять методы массива (например, такое как `forEach`). чтобы с неё сделать массив достаточно просто применить оператор`...`, как у меня в коде. после этого наша **коллекция** станет **массивом**. если что-то еще не понятно - пишите, здесь все свои)